# What is the measure of angle alpha?

Tags: geometry

If AB=CD then $\alpha=$?
[image]

I tried to draw auxiliary lines but none provides an equation that allows the solution

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a path with Euclidean geometry.

[image]

1. Draw line $BE$ so that $\measuredangle CBE = 2\alpha$, and let $F$ on $BE$ such that $DE \cong DF$.
2. Since $BE \cong EC$, we also have $BF \cong DC \cong AB$. Hence $\triangle BAF$ is isoscles. And since $\measuredangle ABE = 180^\circ -  12\alpha$, then $\measuredangle BAF = 6\alpha$ and $\measuredangle FAD = 2\alpha$.
3. Since $\triangle FED$ is also isosceles, it is $\measuredangle FDE = 2\alpha$.
4. By 3. and External Angle Theorem on $\triangle BDC$, $\measuredangle FDB = \alpha$.
5. By 2., 3., and 4. conclude that $\triangle FAD$ and $\triangle BFD$ are isosceles triangles, and therefore $\triangle BAF$ is equilateral, which yields $\alpha = 10^\circ$.

Answer (score 1):

Denote the angles at point $D$ by $D_1$ and $D_2$ so that
$$\angle D = D_1+D_2$$

We see that (which is shown in your second picture):

$$D_2 = 180-3a$$
Which means that:
$$D_1 = 3a$$

**HINT:** Now use the Law of sines. Can you take it from here?

(Just comment if you can't do it, I'll fill in the rest of the anwser then)

Comment: Sorry but 
I couldn't finish ... I don't have the measurements on the sides..can you finish? is it possible to solve without trigonometry?

Comment: @petaarantes I'm sorry, but now when I tried to numerically check my answer I don't know if it's right. I got the equation $$\frac{\sin(8a)}{\sin(3a)} = 2\cos(a)$$ but now I don't really know how to solve for $a$... I'm sorry for that.